# java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Tags: java, jdbc, sqlexception, column-count

The structure of my table:

```
id int AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
title text
url text
age int
```

Here's how I am trying to save data into this table:

```
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into table(title, url, age) values ('\"+title+\",\"+url+\",\"+age+\"')");
System.out.println("Connected database successfully..");
ps.executeUpdate();
```

But when I run the app, I get

> java.sql.SQLException: Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

I guess the problem might be in the **id** column, how to solve it?

Comment: Did you try printing out your prepared statement string fist and make sure it is formatted correctly?  Also, should be using parameters.

Comment: Ugh. I see this so often it's mind boggling. What DBMS are you using? It can not be SQLServer and mySQL. It's one or the other.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is not the `id` column.

From the statement it looks like you have quotes around *all* columns. Therefore it seems to the SQL, that you have only one column

```
'"title","url","age"'
```

What you might want to have is

```
"insert into table(title, url, age) values ('" + title + "','" + url + "'," + age + ")"
```

or even better yet, since it is a *prepared* statement

```
"insert into table(title, url, age) values (?, ?, ?)"
```

Answer (score 3):

Actually, you have a different problem (you're only passing one "value") -

```
PreparedStatement ps=con.prepareStatement("insert into table(title, url, age) "
    + "values (?,?,?)");
ps.setString(1, title);
ps.setString(2, url);
ps.setInt(3, age); // <-- at a guess!
```

You original query put all three values in one string `'\"+title+\",\"+url+\",\"+age+\"'`.

Answer (score 0):

possible mistakes

1. you may be included + sign extra
2. check the DB column order and SQL query order
3. try the same input with prepared statement
4. check the DB name,table name,connecter

The following code worked for me -

```java
try {
  Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
  java.sql.Connection c = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/ems","root","");
  java.sql.Statement s = c.createStatement();
  s.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO employee VALUES('','"+fullname+"','"+address+"','"+homephone+"','"+dob+"','"+mobile+"','"+martial+"','"+nic+"','"+title+"','"+department+"','"+basicsalary+"','"+nname+"','"+nrelationship+"','"+nmobile+"')");
  JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(rootPane, "Saved!");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException ex) {
  Logger.getLogger(employeemanagement.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
}
```